# jquery, css is not applying for tables

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am using tables and some css for user look and feel.
And these tables are made some other jquery plugin like dataTable

http://www.datatables.net/

And my php code is below

```
<table width="100%" id="top_visit_table">
    <thead>
        <tr align="left">
            <th>Product Id</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Product Price</th><th>Number of Views</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php get_views_of_products($user_id);?>
    </tbody>            
</table>
```

And below is the jquery css code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#top_visit_table').dataTable();

    $("#top_visit_table tbody tr:even").addClass('tr_class'); // this gives color to table
    $("#top_visit_table thead tr").addClass('tr_class_head'); // this gives color to table

});

</script>
```

And function code below

```
function get_views_of_products($user_id) {

    $fquery12 = mysql_query("select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_price, pd.products_viewed
                            from products p
                            INNER JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id = p.products_id
                            ORDER BY pd.products_viewed DESC
                            ");

    while($fr12 = mysql_fetch_row($fquery12)) {
        $price = substr($fr12[2], 0, -2);
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$fr12[0]</td>";
            echo "<td>$fr12[1]</td>";
            echo "<td>$price</td>";
            echo "<td>$fr12[3]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

And when i clicked for any `th` element for sorting then `css` is not applied to that `tr` or `td` and below is the image where you can understand it clear.

And CSS code below

```
.tr_class {
    background-color: #CCB;
}

.tr_class_head {
    background-color: #CCE;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are using classes to apply styles and datatables sorts your rows with their classes that could cause 3 odd rows next to each other. I recently used datatables and I made some style changes but mine did not require odd and even row styling. You can try this but I cannot guarantee its success:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent man!.. It worked. thanks.. And can you let me know, how this  code stuf works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use zebra widget or try this one after you do Sorting:

```
$("#top_visit_table tbody tr").find("tr").removeClass("even").filter(":even").addClass("even");
```

Comment: not working out. And I had used zebra widget, but this datatable has some more feature that i would like to implement with that..